# Docker - why do 50 containers running ubuntu take similar amount of RAM as 50x alpine?

Tags: docker

The size of the image of alpine is about 5MB, while of ubuntu - 65MB. So why there is no noticeable difference in RAM usage? If I understand it right, the docker image of X is load into the memory, and then is shared by all the containers (ran from the same image). And then for each container there needs to be created a separate filesystem, etc., and this is why in both cases memory usage was similar.

Is my understanding correct?

```
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..50}
do
    docker container run alpine sleep 60 &
done

$ free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       1.8Gi       4.5Gi       119Mi       1.4Gi       5.6Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       103Mi       1.9Gi

$ ./script.sh 
$ free -mh

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       3.4Gi       2.9Gi       122Mi       1.5Gi       4.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       103Mi       1.9Gi

$ vim script.sh 
$ free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       1.9Gi       4.5Gi       119Mi       1.4Gi       5.6Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       103Mi       1.9Gi

$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..50}
do
    docker container run ubuntu sleep 60 &
done

$ ./script.sh 
$ free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       3.4Gi       2.9Gi       122Mi       1.5Gi       4.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       103Mi       1.9Gi
```

Comment: The fact of Alpine being smalled is related to some (lot) of things that are not present. This don't mean that this things are running processes, so it won't change ram usage

Comment: Two relevant clarifications: an image is just files on disk and is not "loaded into memory"; a container doesn't "run Alpine" or "run Ubuntu", it runs some single program.  You're not doing anything more than measuring the memory usage of two different implementations of `/bin/sleep`.

Comment: See https://amp.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/aypn3o/does_alpine_use_less_memory/

Comment: @DavidMaze I thought that's how docker worked, but how can 50 /bin/sleep processes possibly take up more than 1G of memory?